# High charts gauge-solid and different data sets

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, highcharts, ionic3

I'm using [**High charts gauge-solid**](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/gauge-solid/gray). So I need to create below like chart.
Can you tell me how to give different `data sets` for this chart (each and every color has its own data)?

What I need is this:

[image]

This is what I have tried: [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sampath_lokuge/jm8E4/455/)

```
$(function () {

    $('#gauge').highcharts({

        chart: {
            type: 'solidgauge',
            backgroundColor: 'transparent'
        },

        title: null,

        pane: {
            center: ['50%', '70%'],
            size: '130%',
            startAngle: -120,
            endAngle: 120,
            background: {
                backgroundColor: '#fff',
                innerRadius: '75%',
                outerRadius: '100%',
                shape: 'arc',
                borderColor: 'transparent'
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            enabled: false
        },

        // the value axis
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            stops: [
                [0.1, '#e74c3c'], // red
                [0.5, '#f1c40f'], // yellow
                [0.9, '#2ecc71'] // green
                ],
            minorTickInterval: null,
            tickPixelInterval: 400,
            tickWidth: 0,
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            gridLineColor: 'transparent',
            labels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            title: {
                enabled: false
            }
        },

        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },

        plotOptions: {
            solidgauge: {
                innerRadius: '75%',
                dataLabels: {
                    y: -45,
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    useHTML: true
                }
            }
        },

        series: [{
            data: [83],
            dataLabels: {
                format: '<p style="text-align:center;">{y}%</p>'
            }
        }]
    });

});
```

Comment: How is this even angular related? Why dont you check yourself the API first to see if this is possible?

Comment: I have checked the API. I was unable to find out the method. That is why I have posted here. I have put `angular` here because this is common chart API for most of the frameworks. I need to get the feedback from the wider community here. @Jota.Toledo

Comment: Please provide a detailed explanation of what do you mean by `data sets` and how exactly your chart should behave. This article will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I meant about this section: `series: [{
            data: [83],
            dataLabels: {
                format: '<p style="text-align:center;">{y}%</p>'
            }
        }]`.You can see that we can use only one data set here i.e. `data: [83]`. I have a requirement to put more than one data on it. Like this `[83,45,55]`. Do you know how to do that? @KamilKulig

Answer (score 0):

`data` array can contain more than one value for a series:

```
series: [{
    data: [80, 150, 200]
}]
```

**Live demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/tou6wwxj/

If you want every dial to move only within its own range then you can simply make sure that a proper value is assigned to a point while initializing or updating it.